# REST post method difficulty

Tags: c#, ajax, api, rest, post

There is an application which is used for taking surveys. I want to use REST api and add some questions to the survey. So basically I want to update some pages of the survey. Here are the links of that application.

My surveys name is trial and the page number that I want to update is 2.

fields#updateobject

Here is my code to do. But i think the http call I have used is not correct. and I am not able to figure out how to make the request.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

     class Program
     {
        private static object post;
        private static object response;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunAsync().Wait();
        }

        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            string webReq =      "https://restapi.survey.com/v4/survey/trial/surveypage/2?_method=POST?api_token="/*token goes here*/;
           // $.post{webReq};

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` class for sending requests to any API. Tutorial and examples on sending various requests (GET, POST, etc.) can be found [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client).

Comment: Thank you for help. There are still some error in my code. But i got the logic now.